# What are the principles for writing an optimized sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

If somebody has best Practices for Query Optimization, please write it as an answer.

Comment: this is kind of broad, if you want I can try and give some rather simple ones to watch out for

Comment: how can we write an optimized query? what is the principles for improving the query performance?

Answer (score 4):

Last year I followed a series of videos by [Andy Warren](http://www.sqlshare.com/profiles/18/AndyWarren.aspx) which I would highly recommend:

- [Performance Tuning Puzzle - Part 1](http://www.sqlshare.com/PerformanceTuningPuzzlePart1_758.aspx)
- [Performance Tuning Puzzle - Part 2](http://www.sqlshare.com/PerformanceTuningPuzzlePart2_759.aspx)
- [Performance Tuning Puzzle - Part 3](http://www.sqlshare.com/PerformanceTuningQuizPart3_761.aspx)

Those are good, and he has a [bunch more videos](http://www.sqlshare.com/profiles/18/AndyWarren.aspx) with great performance tips.

Answer (score 3):

learn how to analyze the execution plan.

Answer (score 3):

1. Pull data from the smallest tables first, then join to the larger ones.
2. Use INNER JOIN where you can.
3. Put conditions into the JOIN where possible, rather than in the WHERE clause.

These are very rough, not exhaustive, but  rules of thumb that help me day-to-day.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [MSDN blog of the Query optimization team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/) and [this list](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/20/sql-server-rules-for-optimizining-any-query-best-practices-for-query-optimization/), both refers to SQL-Server